# Elegant way to check if first method return nil and apply another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following:

```
options = args.select{ |arg| arg.respond_to?(:keys) }.first.dup.keep_if {|k| filter_keys.include? k}
```

**EDIT**

```
options = args.select{ |arg| arg.respond_to?(:keys) }.first.select {|k| filter_keys.include? k}
```

`first` sometimes returns `nil` which makes `dup` raises an exception. So I want an elegant way to check if the `first` returns `nil` or no before calling `dup`.

So if `args` is as follows:

```
[{:collection=>["abe", "<mus>", "hest"], :include_blank=>true}]
```

and filter_keys is as follows:

```
filter_keys = %w(include_blank required)
```

The result would be:

```
{:include_blank=>true}
```

Sometimes args would be like:

```
[[["<Africa>", [["<South Africa>", "<sa>"], ["Somalia", "so"]]], ["Europe", [["Denmark", "dk"], ["Ireland", "ie"]]]]]
```

which has no match at all.

or maybe like:

```
[nil, {:collection=>["abe", "<mus>", "hest"], :prompt=>true, :include_blank=>true, :multiple => 'ss'}]
```

which gives also

```
{:include_blank=>true}
```

My trial to this is as follows:

```
if f = args.select{ |arg| arg.respond_to?(:keys) }.first
  options = f.select {|k| filter_keys.include? k}
end
```

This code is supposed to filter the `args` array to get only the matched keys from any hash within it.

But I don't see this code as simple nor elegant at all, since it allocates a new variable.

Comment: You think your original line is more elegant? I have bad news for you :)

Comment: Ah, sorry, it is not more elegant :)

Comment: I would consider a Maybe monad.

Comment: Why `dup+keep_if` instead of simple `select`?

Comment: what if that thing _is_ nil? What would the options be then?

Comment: I was in a hurry writing it, thanks for the mention, I hope you also have a suggestion to the OP question.

Comment: If it is nil, options will be nil.

Comment: @spickermann, please shoot me your thoughts in an answer :)

Comment: What's your code supposed to do? What is `args`, what is `filter_keys`?

Comment: @Stefan Edited the OP.

Comment: As already mentioned, use monads, a good library is https://github.com/pzol/monadic

Comment: @DanilGaponov in my case I can't use an external lib.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I think `args.select{ |arg| arg.respond_to?(:keys) }.first` can be written as `args.detect{ |arg| arg.respond_to?(:keys) }`.

I'd like this way

```
arg = args.detect{|arg| arg.respond_to?(:keys) }
options = arg.select{|k| filter_keys.include? k} if arg
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write is like:

`args.detect { |arg| arg.is_a?(Hash) }.select { |k| filter_keys.include?(k.to_s) }`

keep in mind on `k.to_s` because you provide the filter key list with strings: 
`filter_keys = %w(include_blank required)`
but you have symbols in the args array